# adaptive model predictive control

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink

[image]

In the following link (or above picture) in the controlled system, why are the initial inputs and outputs are subtracted from system inputs/outputs and the resulting signals then delayed? I have indicated these parts in a red rectangle.

http://nl.mathworks.com/help/mpc/ug/adaptive-mpc-control-of-nonlinear-chemical-reactor-using-online-model-estimation.html

Comment: I am not sure, but it may have to do with the outer feedback loop to the MPC.

Comment: One usually subtracts the nominal values to work with deviation variables afterwards. I think the MPC implementation from that example is formulated in deviation variables. If it's a linear MPC and uses linear system matrices (A, B, C, D) then they work with deviation variables.